# Rock paper scissor - homework

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

In a game of rock-paper-scissors, each player chooses to play Rock (R), Paper (P), or Scissors (S). The rules are: Rock breaks Scissors, Scissors cuts Paper, but Paper covers Rock. In a round of rock-paper-scissors, each player's name and strategy is encoded as an array of two elements. Create a `RockPaperScissors` class with a class method winner that takes two 2-element arrays like those above, and returns the one representing the winner:

```
RockPaperScissors.winner(['Armando','P'], ['Dave','S'])  # => ['Dave','S']
```

If either player's strategy is something other than "R", "P" or "S" (case-SENSITIVE), the method should raise a '`RockPaperScissors::NoSuchStrategyError`' exception and provide the message: "Strategy must be one of R,P,S"

If both players use the same strategy, the first player is the winner.

I have my code below. My code is not comparing the two strings correctly in the line

```
(@p1[1,1]==rules["#{p}"]?@p1:@p2).
```

Please help me out.

```
class RockPaperScissors

def winner(p1,p2)
        @p1 = p1
        @p2 = p2
        p = (@p1[1,1]+@p2[1,1]).sort
        rules = Hash.new(0)
        rules = {"PR"=>"R","PS"=>"S", "RS"=>"R", "PP"=>"1","RR"=>"1","SS"=>"1"}
        if rules["#{p}"].nil?
            raise RockPaperScissors::NoSuchStrategyError,"Strategy must be one of R,P,S"
        elseif rules["#{p}"]=="1"
            return @p1
        else 
            print @p1[1,1]
            print rules["#{p}"]
            @p1[1,1]==rules["#{p}"]?@p1:@p2
        end
end

end
t = RockPaperScissors.new
print t.winner(['Armando','R'], ['Dave','S'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some general tips: You don't need `[1,1]`, `[1]` or `.last` would be better. Also no need to initialize `rules` to a new hash, you can only keep the line `rules = {"PR"=>"R"...`. `puts` is more commonly used than `print`. You're overthinking this a bit. Maybe clean up your code, try to simplify it with the tips posted above and see if this gets you unstuck.

Once you are done, have a look at what an idiomatic Ruby solution could look like, but don't submit it as your solution:

```
module RockPaperScissors
  VALID_STRATEGIES = %i(R P S)
  RULES = { R: :S, P: :R, S: :P }

  def self.winner(p1, p2)
    choice1, choice2 = p1.last.intern, p2.last.intern
    unless [choice1, choice2].all? { |s| VALID_STRATEGIES.include? s }
      raise RockPaperScissors::NoSuchStrategyError, "Strategy must be one of R,P,S" 
    end
    return p1 if choice1 == choice2
    RULES[choice1] == choice2 ? p1 : p2
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code looks elegant. Can you also comment why my code is not working in the line @p1[1,1]==rules["#{p}"]?@p1:@p2. Comparison operator is not evaluating two string values.

Comment: @tilthouse That was an answer to OP I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `[1,1]` on an array, you receive an array of size `1` starting from index `1`:

```
[1,2,3][1,1]
# => [2]
[1,2,3][1]
# => 2
```

Because of that when you compare it to the rules, you never get `true`, since no rule is an array...

```
["S"] == "S"
# => false
```

So to fix your code, instead of

```
p = (@p1[1,1]+@p2[1,1]).sort
# ...
(@p1[1,1]==rules["#{p}"]?@p1:@p2)
```

You should try:

```
p = (@p1[1]+@p2[1]).sort
# ...
(@p1[1]==rules[p]?@p1:@p2
```